# File to Array - Java

Tags: java

I have created the following to code to display a file contents to a text area - and it is successful:

```html
BufferedReader in = null;
try {
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\emily\\Documents\\Parts.txt"));
    String str;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        jTextArea1.append("\n"+str);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
} finally {
    try { in.close(); } catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

My problem is that I need each line in an array.  The idea for my proof of concept is that I would be able to enter the command :

```html
jTextArea1 = Arrays.toString(fileArray);
```

The output should then be:
[Part1, Part2, Part3]

In spite of my scouring of the internet, I can't seem to accomplish this. Can anyone tell me how to load these values into an Array (fileArray) instead of writing them into the jTextArea?

Comment: Are you open to adding libraries such as OpenCSV or Commons IO?

Comment: This is the first time I've worked with Java - kinda got thrown into it when someone in Engineering quit, so I'm not sure what that means, but if it helps, I'm open to anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newer classes Path and Files will do.

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\emily\\Documents\\Parts.txt");
try {
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, Charset.defaultCharset());
    String[] array = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
    ...
} catch (IOException e) {
    //Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
    //                                           path.toString(), e);
    System.err.println("Could not read file: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Best would be to use just the List.

---

Add the handling of a possible IOException, probably when the file could not be read.

Comment: This seems like it would be easiest, but I get the following error when I try to complie: "Uncompilable source code - type java.awt.List does not take parameters"

Comment: You must **import java.util.List** - you got the java.awt.List. See [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Comment: Uncompilable source code - unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
??? (Apologies - this is the first time I've worked with Java at my office..)

Comment: Figured it out!  I was trying to display the string...not the array :)  Works perfectly!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
BufferedReader in = null;
try {
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\emily\\Documents\\Parts.txt"));
    String str;
    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] output;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        temp.add(str);
    }
    output = temp.toArray(new String[temp.size()]);
} catch (IOException e) {
} finally {
    try { in.close(); } catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

Comment: So how would I show the array in the jTextArea?  I tried:
            jTextArea2=Arrays.toString(output);
but it doesn't work.  IDE suggests creating the local variable "output"...

Comment: @user3508197 `output` is probably not accessible in the scope you are trying to access it in...Make it a global variable.